# Capture start of long running POST VB.net MVC4

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a subroutine in my Controller

```
<HttpPost>
Sub Index(Id, varLotsOfData)

'Point B. 
'By the time it gets here - all the data has been accepted by server.
```

What I would like to do it capture the Id of the inbound POST and mark, for example, a database record to say "Id xx is receiving data"

The POST receive can take a long time as there is lots of data.

When execution gets to point B I can mark the record "All data received".

Where can I place this type of "pre-POST completed" code?

I should add - we are receiving the POST data from clients that we do not control - that is, it is most likely a client's server sending the data - not a webbrowser client that we have served up from our webserver.

UPDATE:  This is looking more complex than I had imagined.

I'm thinking that a possible solution would be to inspect the worker processes in IIS programatically.  Via the IIS Manager you can do this for example - [How to use IIS Manager to get Worker Processes (w3wp.exe) details information ?](https://abhijitjana.net/2010/11/04/how-to-use-iis-manager-to-get-worker-processes-w3wp-exe-details-information/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, it sounds like HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream might be worth a look. It allows you to begin acting on incoming post data immediately and in "pieces" rather than waiting until the entire post has been received.

An excerpt from [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406798(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ...provides an alternative to using the InputStream propertywhich waits until the whole request has been received. In contrast, the GetBufferlessInputStream method returns the Stream object immediately. You can use the method to begin processing the entity body before the complete contents of the body have been received and asynchronously read the request entity in chunks. This method can be useful if the request is uploading a large file and you want to begin accessing the file contents before the upload is finished.

So you could grab the beginning of the post, and provided your client-facing page sends the ID towards the beginning of its transmission, you may be able to pull that out. Of course, this would be reading raw byte data which would need to be decoded so you could grab the inbound post's ID. There's also a [buffered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.getbufferedinputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) one that will allow the stream to be read in pieces but will also build a complete request object for processing once it has been completely received.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you want to display on the client page that the method is executing and you can show also a loading gif, and when the execution completed, you will show a message to the user that the execution is completed.

The answer is simply: use SignalR

here you can find some references

- [Getting started with signalR 1.x and Mvc4](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4)
- [Creating your first SignalR hub MVC project](http://timjames.me/creating-your-first-signalr-mvc-project/)

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is good, but unfortunately in this Use Case we don't control client.  It comes from the User's own server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom action filter,

Action Filters for executing filtering logic either before or after an action method is called. Action Filters are custom attributes that provide declarative means to add pre-action and post-action behavior to the controller's action methods.

Specifically you'll want to look at the

- **OnActionExecuted** – This method is called after a controller action is executed.

Here are a couple of links:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/03/04/how-to-create-a-custom-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-vb

Here is a lab, but I think it's C#
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Comment: `OnActionExecuting` seems a better bet - however in testing it is only triggered once the POST data has _all_ been received at the server.